# Check a condition statement stored in a string

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, expression-evaluation

Suppose I have a condition and its stated in NSSring like:

```
NSString *someString = @"4%2 == 0";
```

Is there any way I could use it in a if statement as a condition? Just like

```
if(extractConditionUsingSomeLogic(someString)){
    NSLog(@"Yayyy");
}
```